# Ruby class loading mechanism

Tags: ruby

I'm beginning with the Ruby programming language and I'm interested in understanding it in depth before I start studding the Rails framework.

I'm currently a little disappointed because everybody seams to care only about the Rails framework, and other aspects of the language are just not discussed in depth, such as its class loading mechanism.

Considering that I'm starting by doing some desktop/console experiments, I would like to better understand the following matters:

1. Is it a good practice to place each Ruby class in a separate Ruby file? (*.rb)
2. If I have, let's say .. 10 classes .. and all of them reference each other, by instantiating one another and calling each other's methods, should I add a 'require' statement in each file to state which classes are required by the class in that file? (just like we do with 'import' statements in each Java class file?)
3. Is there a difference in placing a 'require' statement before or after (inside) a class declaration?
4. What could be considered a proper Ruby program's 'entry point'? It seams to me that any .rb script will suffice, since the language doesn't have a convention like C or Java where we always need a 'main' function of method.
5. Is class loading considered a 'phase' in the execution of a Ruby program? Are we supposed to load all the classes that are needed by the application right at the start?
6. Shouldn't the interpreter itself be responsible for finding and loading classes as we run the code that needs them? By searching the paths in the $LOAD_PATH variable, like Java does with its $CLASSPATH?

Thank you.

Comment: That's too many questions. Please reduce them to the two or three you *REALLY* want to know about. Stack Overflow prefers one per page, but a couple closely related ones are OK. Six... eh... not so much.

Comment: Regarding the fact that so many like Rails... it's flashy. Where I work we don't do Rails, and, instead we're writing in-house back-end code in straight Ruby. If we need a web service it's done in Sinatra.

Answer (score 5):

In general terms, it's a good practice to create a separate `.rb` file for each Ruby class unless the classes are of a utility nature and are too trivial to warrant separation. An instance of this would be a custom Exception derived class where putting it in a separate file would be more trouble than its worth.

Tradition holds that the name of the class and the filename are related. Where the class is called `ExampleClass`, the file is called `example_class`, the "underscored" version of same. There are occasions when you'll buck this convention, but so long as you're consistent about it there shouldn't be problems. The Rails ActiveSupport auto-loader will help you out a lot if you follow convention, so a lot of people follow this practice.

Likewise, you'll want to organize your application into folders like `lib` and `bin` to separate command-line scripts from back-end libraries. The command-line scripts do not usually have a `.rb` extension, whereas the libraries should.

When it comes to `require`, this should be used sparingly. If you structure your library files correctly they can all load automatically once you've called `require` on the top-level one. This is done with the `autoload` feature.

For example, `lib/example_class.rb` might look like:

```
class ExampleClass
  class SpecialException < Exception
  end

  autoload(:Foo, 'example_class/foo')

  # ...
end
```

You would organize other things under separate directories or files, like `lib/example_class/foo.rb` which could contain:

```
class ExampleClass::Foo
  # ...
end
```

You can keep chaining `autoloads` all the way down. This has the advantage of only loading modules that are actually referenced.

Sometimes you'll want to defer a `require` to somewhere inside the class implementation. This is useful if you want to avoid loading in a heavy library unless a particular feature is used, where this feature is unlikely to be used under ordinary circumstances.

For example, you might not want to load the YAML library unless you're doing some debugging:

```
def debug_export_to_yaml
  require 'yaml'

  YAML.dump(some_stuff)
end
```

If you look at the structure of common Ruby gems, the "entry point" is often the top-level of your library or a utility script that includes this library. So for an example `ExampleLibrary`, your entry point would be `lib/example_library.rb` which would be structured to include the rest on demand. You might also have a script `bin/library_tool` that would do this for you.

As for when to load things, if there's a very high chance of something getting used, load it up front to pay the price early, so called "eager loading". If there's a low chance of it getting used, load it on demand, or leave it "lazy loaded" as it's called.

Have a look at the source of some simple but popular gems to get a sense of how most people structure their applications.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to help you with the first one:

> 1. Is it a good practice to place each Ruby class in a separate Ruby file? (*.rb)

It comes down to how closely related those classes are. Let's see a few examples. Look this class: https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/master/lib/resque.rb
, it `"imports"` the functionality of several classes that, although they work together, they are not closely related to be bundled together.

On the other hand, take a look at this module: https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/master/lib/resque/errors.rb. It bundles 5 different classes, but these do belong together since they are all essentially representing the same.

Additionally, from a design standpoint a good rule of thump could be asking yourself, who else is using this class/ functionality (meaning which other parts of the code base needs it)?

Let's say that you want to represent a `Click` and `WheelScroll` performed by a `Mouse`. It would make more sense in this trivial example, that those classes be bundled together:

```
module ComputerPart
   class Mouse; end
   class WheelScroll; end
   class Click; end
end
```

Finally, I would recommend that you peruse the code of some of these popular projects to kind of get the feeling how the community usually make these decisions.

Answer (score 0):

1.) I follow this practice, but it is not necessary, you can put a bunch of classes in one file if you want.

2.) If the classes are in the same file, no, they will all be accessible when you run the script. If they are in separate files then you should require them, you can also require the entire directory that the file(self) is in.

3.)Yes, it should be at the top of the file.

4.) In ruby everything descends from the Main object, the Interpreter just handles creating it for you. If you are writing OO ruby and not just scripts, then the entry point will be the init method of the first class you call.

5.) Yes, before the program runs it loads up all the dependencies.

6.) I think it does this, all you have to do is require the proper files at the top of the files, after that you can use them as you wish without having to implicitly load them again.